# How can we force our code to calculate correlation when P is less than 0.05?

Tags: r, correlation

I am calculating the correlation map between two datasets. I got results which look like:[image]

```
dir1 <- list.files("D:thly", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
dir2 <- list.files("D:002", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
file_tot <- array(dim = c(1440, 720, 11, 2))

}
```

I would like to calculate the correlation only when the P value is lower than 0.05.

Comment: That's a lot of correlations. Are you sure that 0.05 is the most appropriate cutoff?

Comment: @joran Agreed - I much prefer 0.045 myself ;)

Comment: @csgillespie Woah, woah! That's pretty extreme. I was going to say they should try 0.048 and go from there.

Comment: @joran I'm British so I'm a bit more conservative. I also believe that Fisher disagreed with the whole "0.048" movement.

Comment: Google "multiple comparisons". 1 in 20 of your correlations will be below 0.05 just by random chance. That will be a lot of spurious correlations.

Comment: @Barry Remember that 0.05 is "just a number". A nice number, but "still just a number".

Comment: @csgillespie At least one Italian seems to prefer `.05*N`.

Answer (score 4):

You question isn't very (i.e. not at all) reproducible, but this should get you started. The trick is to calculate all correlations, but only plot/return the ones above your threshold. The function `cor.test` performs a correlation test.

```
return_cor = function(x, y)  {
    z = cor.test(x,y)
    if(z[[3]] < 0.05) {
        return(z[[4]])
    } else { 
        return(NA) 
    }
}
```

and a test:

```
x = rnorm(10); y = rnorm(10)
R> return_cor(x, x)
cor 
  1 
R> return_cor(x, y)
[1] NA
```

So

```
resultsr = apply(file_tot, c(1,2), function(x) {return_cor(x[,1],x[,2])})
```

Comment: Try it and see: `return_cor(x, y)` where you not what x and y are.

Comment: Run the function cor.test - it returns a bunch of stuff. The values `cor.test(x, y)[[5]]` gives the p-value, whilst `cor.test(x,y)[[3]]` gives  r.

Comment: @Barry You're not going to get help by posted unreadable and unreproducible code snippets in the comments. Edit your question to be reproducible.

Comment: @Barry Try that (I've now tested it).

Comment: @Barry Try it now - I've included a test